# Imagick (Imagemagick) Defect in Debian Sqeeze (6)

Tags: php, imagemagick, debian, imagick

I have huge troubles running my cakephp application now.

after upgrading vom lenny to squeeze (even tried a complete reinstall of sqeeze) imagick is so incredible slow that it simply shuts down my server.
I have several image galleries which use imagick to create thumbs.

50 images needed less then 30 seconds (2000x1200 pixel) on lenny. NOW it needs more than an hour..
Processor is at 100% for the complete time making other processes like apache very slow.
is this a known bug in squeeze?
it is making me crazy!

I even tried to run the application of other servers. a friend gave me access to his archlinux + nginx. fast as a rocket (less then 23 seconds).
it is definitly a sqeeze problem.

i simply installed it via "apt-get install imagemagick"
and added the php extension "php-imagick"

details:
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2010-11-16 Q16

Comment: I have had no problems using ImageMagick's commandline clients (`convert` and `mogrify`) on Squeeze. I regularly use them to convert large galleries. So I'd rule out a bug inside ImageMagick itself. But really, this belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: Just to be sure: you did install `php5-imagick` instead of `php-imagick` I hope? Can't find the latter in the default repos...

Comment: yes, php5-imagick of course :) the other ohne probably doesnt exist, extacly. PHPThumb uses the class access I think. either way - it works on all systems except my brandnew squeeze..

Comment: PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

5734 www-data  19   0  312m  60m 2528 R 99.6  5.9   0:07.12 convert

i dont know what else i could check..

Comment: Is this a Debian 6 (squeeze) specific problem or is it also present in Debian 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution seems to be to **downgrade imagemagick**:

http://howto.at/2011/08/02/super-speed-up-virtuozzo-with-debian-6-and-imagemagick/

There's a debian bug (**#638409**) opened about this, seems to be caused by imagemagick's use of openmp:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=638409

Since we have this problem ourselves, we will be trying both solutions shortly :)

Comment: i found the solution in a forum: http://faq.hosteurope.de/index.php?cpid=17180 - basically you need to manually configurate it on non-multi-processor systems

Comment: This was indeed the problem and configuring without openmp fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by cosimo above it is a known but. I found an elegant solution by **recompiling the packages without the openmp-extension** according to [A.M. Popa](http://mapopa.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/php-image-slow-smp-magick-on-ubuntu.html) (for Debian) and [J. Jarolim](http://johannes.jarolim.com/blog/2011/11/21/extreme-slow-imagemagick-on-vps-with-ubuntu/) (for Ubuntu). Assuming you had installed `imagemagick` before:

```
$ apt-get buil-dep imagemagick
$ apt-get source imagemagick
$ cd imagemagick-6.5.7.8/
$ sudo vi debian/rules
```

add ~ line 39 `--disable-openmp`:

```
--disable-openmp
```

Rebuild the package and reinstall:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -b
$ cd ..
$ dpkg -i libmagickcore3* libmagickwand3*
```

Comment: You can use `sed -i "s/export STATIC_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS :=/export STATIC_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS := \\\\\n\t--disable-openmp/" debian/rules` to add the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Also try [GMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php), minimal modifications on source and cool new features.