# creating pictures with imagemagick is too slow. how to improve?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm coding a little CMS, where you can upload several images.
These images are converted into *3 versions (big, mid und thumbnail size)* with imagemagick.

The problem is that imagemagick needs 5 minutes for creating these 3 versions of 4 pictures (which were uploaded).

here is the part with the imagemagick commands:

```
foreach($upIMGS as $key => $filename){
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path.$filename);
    if ($width > $height) $size = "x96";
    else $size = "96x";

    exec(P_IMAGEMAGICK." ".$path.$filename." -resize $size -gravity center -crop 96x96+0+0 +repage ".$path."th-".$filename);
    exec(P_IMAGEMAGICK." ".$path.$filename." -resize 320x320 ".$path."hl-".$filename);
    exec(P_IMAGEMAGICK." ".$path.$filename." -resize 514x ".$path."fl-".$filename);

    unlink($path.$filename);
}
```

[the $upIMGS is an array with all the filenames of the recently uploaded images]

I mean.. it does work, but toooo slow and after 5min the server gives me an error. some of the files are generated and some are not...

Would be very nice if you can give me a tip.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you try isolating the issue? Is some of the three substantially slower than others? What if you try the command line items one-by-one separately? Is the server under heavy load?

Comment: OK. I found out that the generated versions of the first (of the 4 uploaded) image is made immediately. but the other ones (the 2nd, 3rd and 4th) take a long long time...

Comment: Probably new instance of ImageMagick is started for each conversion and if the first three are fast, to me it would suggest that some other part of the code is the issue. Can't pinpoint it to you, though. :-(

Comment: what is the hosting company and tariff?

Comment: @Edu What could be an alternative.. how can i prevent imagemagick from starting new instances? Do you think the loop causes the problem?

Comment: What is your environment? There seems to be [one known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817599/imagick-imagemagick-defect-in-debian-sqeeze-6) in certain Debian/Ubuntu version. On the other hand some problem also mentioned in [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) page comments section, possibly worse in Windows.

Comment: Why don't you use javascript Worker threads to resize the image on the client, and then send it to the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue, but I was only passing through the images once to resize them from their original 2592x1944 to 300xbestFit or bestFitx300

I am using the PHP class imagick instead of command lines but I cut my time in half by changing to -scale or scaleImage in my case. Here is a snippet of my test code.

```php
while ($images = readdir($handle)) {
    // check to see if the first or second character is a '.' or '..', 
    // if so then remove from list
    if (substr($images,0,1) != '.') {
        //Check files to see if there extensions match any of the following image extensions. 
        // GLOB_BRACE looks for all glob criteria within the {braces}
        $images = glob($dir."{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
        // the glob function gives us an array of images
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            // parse the data given and remove the images/ $dir, 
            // imagemagick will not take paths, only image names.
            $i++;
            list ($dir, $image) = split('[/]', $image);
            echo $i, " ", $image, "<br />";

            $magick = new Imagick($dir."/".$image);
            $imageprops = $magick->getImageGeometry();

            if ($imageprops['width'] <= 300 && $imageprops['height'] <= 300) {
                // don't upscale
            } else {

                // 29 Images at 2592x1944 takes 11.555036068 seconds -> 
                // output size = 300 x 255
                $magick->scaleImage(300,300, true);

                // 29 Images at 2592x1944 takes 23.3927891254 seconds -> 
                // output size = 300 x 255
                //$magick->resizeImage(300,300, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
                $magick->writeImage("thumb_".$image);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am processing 29 images at 2592x1944 and went from 23.3927891254 seconds to 11.555036068 seconds. I hope this helps.

**Edit:**

In addition to what I said above I just ran into to the following, which might be helpful, on [ImageMagick v6 Examples -- API & Scripting](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/api/#speed):

- "Shell scripts are inherently slow. It is interpreted, require
  multiple steps and extra file handling to disk. This is of course
  better thanks to the new IM v6 option handling, allowing you to do a
  large number of image processing operations in a single command. Even
  so you can rarely can do everything in a single `convert` command, so
  you often have to use multiple commands to achieve what you want."
- "When reading large or even a large number of images, it is better to
  use a [Read
  Modifier](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read_mods) to
  resize, or crop them, as IM does not them read in the full image,
  thus reducing its memory requirement."
- "If you call ImageMagick as an Apache module it will also reduce
  startup time, as parts will be loaded once and kept available for
  multiple use, rather than needing re-loading over and over. This may
  become more practical in the future with a permanently running
  'daemon' IM process."

Answer (score 3):

This example may help as it loads the main image into the memory and works on that to make the other images:

```
$cmd = " input.jpg \( -clone 0 -thumbnail x480 -write 480_wide.jpg +delete \)". 
" \( -clone 0 -thumbnail x250 -write 250_wide.jpg +delete \) ". 
" \( -clone 0 -thumbnail x100 -write 100_wide.jpg +delete \) -thumbnail 64x64! null: ";
exec("convert $cmd 64_square.jpg ");
```

This is creating 4 different size images.

Answer (score 2):

Wait what? It should not take five minutes to generate 12 pictures from three uploaded pictures.

I don't see the rest of your code, but why is your getimagesize path $path.$filename but your unlink P_UPLOADS.$value? Is there a reason they are different? Where does $value come from anyway, it is not defined in your foreach() loop. Maybe you simply have a bug that causes the script to hang. I've used ImageMagick (though not with exec(), but with actual class) and it's been very fast.

Have you run diagnostics on your foreach loop()? Like print out milliseconds it takes to do each of those exec() commands.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've changed now the variable-names. (I changed them for better understanding)

Answer (score 0):

A little trick would be to create the largest picture first and then create subsequent pictures from this one, not original.

However, 5 min seems too much for just 12 images anyway.
You have to do some investigations.

- does the resize take considerable time if the source is relatively small (say 1024x768)?
- does it take the same time called directly from the shell?

If the delay is inevitable, you may wish to move resize facility into dedicated server, put them in the queue and check the process with simple AJAX snippet.

Comment: i tried out your trick ("create subsequent pictures from this one") ... it does not really make it faster. the sizes i used are "1000x665", "3400x2000", "1840x1200" and "2130x1500" .. still the same problem